# What to tell to a rejected candidate?

Tags: interviewing, india

We're currently in the process of hiring candidates for a software development position. The company is small, and the interviews are for trainee level position, for which we're seeking candidates who are either freshers or who have only a bit of relevant experience. That's why little filtering of résumés is done, and most of the candidates are called for an in-person interview.

I am tasked with interviewing candidates at this point. If there are any good ones but I find but are such that they're not an immediate yes/no, then I have a discussion with my boss before hiring. And I am a technical person, not HR.

I interviewed such a candidate, and he had a good résumé, but the interview didn't go as well. I had a review of him with my boss but the latter said that the candidate didn't have some needed skills, so he got rejected.

The candidate called up unexpectedly two days later to inquire about the results of his interview. Since I was not prepared to answer at that moment and didn't want to tell him he wasn't selected(a situation similar to a candidate asking at the end of the interview how he did), I told him someone would be contacting him later to let him know.

I know saying that is the de facto standard response given to a candidate, but I don't really know what I should be telling him if he were to call again. Should I be taking any more steps to tell him the result or not do anything at all and hope he gets the hint?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46192/discussion-on-question-by-cst1992-what-to-tell-to-a-rejected-candidate).

Comment: @FirstStep if you have disagreements with the moderation, please [create a new meta post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to discuss that. cst1992, if you have new information it is most helpful to [edit] the question to include this information rather than posting it in comments, as comments become unwieldy.

Comment: @enderland Got it.

Comment: I think that he deserves the truth. I know that that is what I would want. Anything else is not likely to help him, so why not tell him the truth?

Comment: Don't tell him anything. He is already free :)

Comment: @ManojKumar are You serious? Telling someone they **won't** get the job You are making them free for seeking for another job. If you hide taht information from them you are wasting their time by waiting for your, hopefully positive, response. Ignorance is mean there.

Comment: @Crowley He's kidding.

Comment: @Crowley Who has forced them to wait for rejection before pursuing another opportunity? Until you have an offer letter, you don't have the job. If the candidate is naive enough to keep waiting for a company to *explicitly* say so, he just needs to grow up.

Comment: @MaskedMan If I have hope of getting some job I devote some time for checking it. And that (small ammount of) time is spared when I am sure I won't get that job. I can reject that possibility from any comparisons I am about to do for other jof offers.

Comment: Several days have passed and OP has still not clarified his description, so I am changing my upvote to downvote. To reiterate (because a comment asking OP to clarify was deemed "not helpful" and moved to chat), question title and early part of the description says candidate is already rejected, the later part says candidate could still be hired. As an aside, this is probably the first time I voted "unclear what you're asking" to mean "*you* are unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @MaskedMan the "still be hired" part was for special cases. The company is a small one, so you could say there isn't an as-much concrete process of hiring as in mid-to-large companies. The specific candidate I was asking about has been specifically rejected. I will restructure the question to make everything clear.

Comment: @MaskedMan I have restructured the question.

Comment: If the candidate has already been rejected, then he is not a "special case" and he cannot "still be hired". You are asking about a candidate who has been rejected and is not a special case. So why are you wondering "what if he were a special case"?

Comment: @MaskedMan Did you check out the edited question?

Comment: @cst1992 Yes, I did and now you have edited out the "still be hired" part which led to the whole discussion. Now my [previous comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32669735#32669735) applies. If candidate is already rejected, why don't you just tell him so?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You do not owe this person an explanation of why he was not selected. And it is almost always a bad move to try to tell them. If he calls though, you do owe him a straight answer on whether he was selected.

It would have been kinder to have told him he was not selected rather than pretend a decision has not been made. Keeping someone believing they are in the running for a position when they are not is cruel. This person will most likely continue to call until you tell him.

In this case, since you told him someone would contact him later, you owe him the call to tell him that he was not selected. This was your mistake, you need to fix it. Do not delegate this task to someone else.

**Hinting is an ineffective communication tool in virtually all circumstances.**  This is something you need to learn not to do. If you are in a position where you are making hiring decisions, you need to be able to give people a firm and clear no. Hiring is a management task and managers are often the people who have to give out bad news. You need to learn to do so.

Write down what you want to say to tell a candidate that he has not been selected and then practice it. I would normally say something to the effect of he was not the person chosen to fill the position. And then wish him good luck in his job search. If he asks for feedback on why, tell him that it is the company policy not to give that type of feedback. (Most likely if you check with HR that is the case as very few companies want to get into that particular can of worms.) But write out what you think someone might ask you and the responses and practice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46317/discussion-on-answer-by-hlgem-what-to-tell-to-a-rejected-candidate).

Answer (score 102):

I have two standard responses. Before a decision is made:

> I appreciate your interest and enthusiasm. The process is still underway and you won't hear from us until it is complete.

After a decision is made, all unsuccessful candidates (not just those who contact for followup) get a note that thanks them for their interest, and includes the sentence

> We have offered the position to another candidate, who has accepted it.

I **never** tell people specifically where they fell short. You may think this is a nice thing to do, but causes the **majority** of followuppers to reply arguing with you - actually I have excellent communication skills! - I think you'll find jQuery excellence is not required for that job! - I defy you to find anyone with better graphic design skills than me! - or insisting that you consider them for a different position in the firm. (I used to say we would "keep your resume in case something came up", but that caused one person to email me once a month asking if anything had come up yet, so I removed the sentence from then on.)

Occasionally I include an extra sentence in this email. I told one applicant

> This was a very close decision and if we had two positions, I would have offered you one. Should we need to grow further in the near future, may we get in touch to offer you first refusal?

and several others:

> This was a very close decision and your skills are excellent. Many of our clients ask us to help them hire developers. Should such an opportunity arise in the near future, do I have your permission to pass along your resume and a brief summary of our interview?

People do generally consent to these :-).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46191/discussion-on-answer-by-kate-gregory-what-to-tell-to-a-rejected-candidate).

Comment: Excellent answer as always Kate. Can you clarify whether you do provide (candid) feedback for candidates who calmly and professionally ask for it? And another approach I sometimes see to this is for hiring managers to provide some brief feedback explaining the choice as a courtesy but replying with a form mail and ignoring (and potentially blacklisting) candidates who react unprofessionally (i.e those who argue or say something like "*you just lost out on one of the greatest minds of this generation!*"). Would that work for people who want to avoid sending boilerplate rejections?

Comment: I just checked back through my hiring emails and astonishingly 100% of the people who asked for feedback became pestery. So yes, while I did once try to say things like "in a consulting firm being able to give short presentations is important" I can see why I stopped.

Answer (score 17):

You already wrote exactly what you should tell him.

"[Sorry, but] unfortunately [you] did not have the skills we were seeking."

Keep it short, simple, and to the point. Nothing more.

Comment: I suggest to avoid absolutes ("you did not have the skills") and instead phrase your feedback in terms of how you, as the interviewer, perceived the candidate - "we perceived your skills in X as insufficient". This is generally accepted better by candidates, especially if you can back it up with a reference to a relevant part of the interview.

Comment: @Kos - to a certain extent, it's all relative, really. A truthful answer that also probably doesn't sting as much is, simply "we had other candidates we felt were stronger" - which is certainly less absolute than "your skills were insufficient."

Answer (score 9):

Just tell the guy that he has not been selected, a simple email can do that job. For example:

> Hi CandidateName,
>
> Thank you for the follow up. Although your results were pretty impressive and your skill set is competitive, we have decided to move forward with another candidate for this position.
>
> Thank you for your interest and best of luck in your search.

You will be doing him a favor. Because he is definitely waiting and he probably thinks that he did great at the test and got the job. It also might be (it's the case with me for example when I am looking for a job) that he operates and processes one application at a time, so until he hears a Yes or a No, he does not move on with the next application(Which as mentioned by user [HLGEM](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/93/hlgem) in the comments, it is not a good practice).

So *Just Do It*.

Comment: you should never work only one application at a time when job searching. Many companies do not contact the people they did not choose. You are wasting your time when you do this.

Comment: Well, in that particular time (after finishing the technical interview and waiting for their decision) I actually get my next target and start gathering information, I then apply when I hear the no. Maybe it is just me (I never looked for a job and I had time - always busy / currently working) so usually I take my time with things. But thanks for pointing that out. I will edit.

Comment: Don't edit it out, there are, as you pointed out, people who really are waiting to move on.

Comment: @HLGEM What does he say when he gets a job offer elsewhere? Perhaps: "I recently interviewed at cst1992's company and they promised to contact me shortly. Please give me a few days to make my decision." He may miss out on another job thanks to the OP's humbug.

Comment: I would love this answer if the middle sentence just ended at "position". Don't include "that had a few more years of experience". You have no obligation to explain or justify your decision or give people something to argue with or something a lawyer could prove was either not true or not relevant to the position. Things you don't include can't be used against you and to be honest, including them doesn't really help the candidate in any way. It might make you feel like you're letting them down easy - not their fault someone was better - but it doesn't, does it?

Comment: @KateGregory I absolutely meant no harm or offense for the candidate. It is  just a "spammed reason" for the candidate to move on. I built that on some personal assumption / opinion. I apologize and I will edit and remove it and will not include it in future. Thank you for the lesson and I totally agree.

Comment: Saying "your skill set is competitive" when he was rejected because his skill set wasn't, means you're still lying.

Comment: Remco: There are lots of people whose skill set is competitive. If you interview two of them for one open position then you will tell one of them “sorry, your skill set is competitive but we hired someone else”.

Answer (score 8):

In this case just tell them the truth, it's what I do as the technical person.

'Sorry, I don't know, it's not my decision to make. I think HR will be contacting everyone who was interviewed.'

Then if they bug me for HR's contact I give it, and they can chat all they like with HR.

Comment: This is what I meant to say, probably I should have worded it differently.

Comment: This is also a good response when the candidate has your direct contact information. Particularly when it is true (and it sounds like this is the case here).

Answer (score 2):

Candidate A was chosen, candidates B, C, D,... were not chosen. Period.

When Candidate B calls for the results tell him the truth. "I am sorry, we have chosen another candidate." This sentence says everything needed: There was at least one candidate more suitable for the job than they were. Thanking them for their effort and wiching them good luck in their seek is optional (and recomendable) extra. Telling them why they were not chosen is unnecessary.

Actually, you (You, personally, or your HR) should have sent them the message two days ago.

---

**Edit**

In the case that you are rejecting them only, the position is still open, but not for this perticullar candidate, you can reject him saying "I am sorry, but we are looking for candidate with different set of skills (someone else)." There is absolutely no room for possible negotiation.

Still, You should have informed them that you are not about to hire them at the time, when the [final] decision was made.

Giving someone false hope is not cruel, it is mean.

Comment: The position is still open. Whenever it fills, the candidate will be contacted.

Comment: @cst1992 Sorry, I misunderstood. But does the candidate, we are takling about, have a chance to get the job?

Comment: No, he lacks the mindset for lasting on the job long term.

Comment: Be careful about the "different skillset" one - it *could* lead to an argument  - he may protest that he actually has the desired skills but didn't effectively communicate that in the interview.

Comment: @colmde The interview was held to assess the required skillset. They have failed at it. Game over. You can silence them stating "All skills requirements were already adressed during the interview." (You are crying on the wrong grave.)

Comment: @Crowley True, but I'm just saying you cst1992 be inviting an argument when s/he might rather not.

Comment: @colmde That way anything he said could lead to [poor] argument. Even the sentence "Your application was discarded", which just states the fact, may lead to argument "But I am capable to contitue..." I think 99 of 100 people will let it go, and the one, who doesn't, is the one you really do not want to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If the candidate is absolutely, unequivocally out of the running, a simple

> Sorry to let you down, but we do not feel like you would be a good fit for the role. ... (candidate asks why) Unfortunately, I cannot go into specifics. I wish you luck in your search.

Otherwise, I like Kate Gregory's "I appreciate your interest and enthusiasm. The process is still underway and you won't hear from us until it is complete."

---

When I'm the sole decision maker, I let them know at the end of the interview whether we want to move forward or not. Only rarely do I not know immediately.

Comment: I am the sole interviewer, but not the sole decision maker. If I were to say no and the candidate were reviewed, he could still get hired. However, my opinion has value.

Comment: Then your response was appropriate so long as someone actually has a task to follow up when you confirm that he will not be hired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the answers here. "didn't have the skills" is way too vague to have any meaning. You wanted a neurosurgeon and he was a gardener? You wanted someone who was fluent in Hindi and English and he spoke only Hindi and Tamil? Some skills can be learned on the job, some are prerequisites.

He shouldn't have been interviewed if he didn't have the "hard" skills needed. As far as "soft" skills (interpersonal, organizational, social, etc.) those are very hard to accurately quantify in an interview. Interviews and resumes are a very poor way to determine how well someone will do in a job, but like the old saying about democracy being a bad form of government, but better than any other, we've no choice to use resumes, interviews and personal recommendations to fill job vacancies.

You should be careful to distinguish between factual deficiencies (PhD required) and subjective ones (poor communication skills). Also, it must be said that no decision is final until the position has been filled, and employee has showed up at work. If the decision maker agreed with you that he is not a "finalist", then you should have told him so - since he wouldn't ever qualify for the position.

In the USA, there are legal constraints on what an employer should and should not say to a candidate. It is a judgement call whether you tell the candidate any specific deficiencies which you identified. Of course, it should be obvious that you would only tell him about things he could improve. (e.g. "We chose someone with Microsoft PowerPoint experience" compared to "We chose someone with more industry experience").

My practice was to keep it short:"Your resume impressed us [otherwise, you wouldn't have interviewed him] and perhaps "and you interviewed well" but we chose another candidate". When a candidate impressed me, but lacked maybe one necessary prerequisite, I might mention something about that, as long as it had been discussed during his interview. It's a bad idea for things not discussed to be brought in at this point.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Comment: I also believe this post has some good ideas that just need to be brought in shape. Right now, it's difficult to upvote.